# column-wise merging of multiple files in specific order

Tags: bash, paste

I want to perform column-wise merging of multiple files considering the increasing order of file names. To be specific, I have renamed 163 files as 1.lrr, 2.lrr,3.lrr...163.lrr and I used following command to merge multiple files:

```
    Paste -d "\t" *.lrr > all_samples.lrr
```

However, It combined column in some strange order of filenames. It started file merging with the file 100.lrr instead of file 1.lrr. Later on, it combined column from files 101.lrr until 109.lrr. Is it possible to modify this command so that it also considers numerically sorting of file names while merging the column?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Instead of 1,2,3.. , if you have named your files a,b,c..., it would have worked. Glob patterns do alphabetical sort.

Comment: if you had used 001, 002 etc. you probably wouldn't run into the issue...lexical order then is identical to the numerical order (or if you don't like leading zeros, add 100 to all 101.lrr .. 263.lrr)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
paste $(ls | grep -E "*.lrr" | sort -n) > all_samples.lrr
```